# Using Pagination with collections in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am trying to paginate a collection but it's throwing an error

```
public function city_listing($city){

    $products=product::where('city',$city)->get()->paginate(10);

    $data = array();
    foreach($products as $product){
        $product_id = $product->id;

        $images = Image::where('product_id',$product_id)->get()->all();

        $product['images']=$images;
        $data[] = $product;
    }
    return view('home.search_file')->with('data',$data);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wgAL.png)`

I tried paginating a collection of data but it is not working as expected

Comment: Paginate works from eloquent query builder, remove get() from your eloquent query $products=product::where('city',$city)->paginate(10);

Comment: And use relationship for product images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup the `images` relation on the product model

**Product.php**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

You can now eager load the images (and remove the `get()` before `paginate()`)

```
public function city_listing($city){

    $products = product::where('city',$city)->with('images')->paginate(10);

    return view('home.search_file')->with('data',$products);
}
```